# How can I get the service name from code for a Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-service-runtime

I am looking for a way to get the deployment name for a cloud service from C# code using `RoleEnviroment` class or something similar so that if my service is deployed at `myservice.cloudapp.net` I get `myservice`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Gaurav is partially correct.  You will have to use the Service Management API. Be careful with your terminology - Deployment Name is typically a GUID representing the current deployment of the service code.  You are looking for the ServiceName.  Using the Service Management API, you can issue a request to [`Get Hosted Service Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx#bk_dns).  The property ServiceName in the response object is the DNS prefix you are looking for:

> The name of the cloud service. This name is the DNS prefix name and
>   can be used to access the cloud service. For example, if the cloud
>   service name is MyService you could access the cloud
>   service by calling: http://MyService.cloudapp.net

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make use of [`Service Management REST API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460812.aspx) to get the cloud service name. The operation is a bit convoluted one!

Here're the steps you would need to do:

1. Get the deployment id. This you will be able to get from RoleEnvironment.
2. Next you fetch the list of all cloud services in your subscription. For this you would need to perform [`List Hosted Services`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460781.aspx) operation.
3. Then for each cloud service, you would need to get the properties. For this you would need to perform [`Get Hosted Service Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx). Also make sure that you provide `embed-detail=true` query string parameter.
4. In the response you'll get, you would need to find the `PrivateID` attribute and match it with your deployment id.

I wrote a blog post long time back which has some code to let you do something like this: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/03/16/programmatically-finding-deployment-slot-from-code-running-in-windows-azure/.

Comment: Means I have to upload a certificate along the deployment just to get the name? I will take a look at it.

Comment: @s093294: Yes, and you'll have to write code that loads that certificate and makes REST requests. That's like several dozens lines of code extra. I agree that it's an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

```
async public Task<List<XDocument>> GetAzureServices()
    {
        String uri = String.Format("https://management.core.windows.net /{0}/services/hostedservices ", _subscriptionid);
        List<XDocument> services = new List<XDocument>();

        HttpClient http = GetHttpClient();

        Stream responseStream = await http.GetStreamAsync(uri);

        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
            var svcs = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "HostedService");
            foreach (XElement r in svcs)
            {
                XDocument vm = new XDocument(r);
                services.Add(vm);
            }
       }

        return services;
    }

public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        string CertThumbprint = _certthumbprint;
        X509Certificate2 managementCert = FindX509Certificate(CertThumbprint);
        if (managementCert != null)
        {
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(managementCert);
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            return httpClient;
        }
        return null;
    }
private static X509Certificate2 FindX509Certificate(string thumbprint)
    {
        X509Store certificateStore = null;
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

        try
        {
            certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            var certificates = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
            if (certificates.Count > 0)
            {
                certificate = certificates[0];
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (certificateStore != null) certificateStore.Close();
        }

        return certificate;
    }
```

you need to specify subcriptionId and certificate thumbprint